# django boolean field in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to display a message on a template that varies based on the boolean field in my model.

For my model I have:

```
Class Example(models.Model):
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Views.py

```
def home(request):
    example = Example.objects
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'example': example})
```

home.html

```
{% for x in example.all %}
{% if x.completed %}
    <p>Congratulations!</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Try again!</p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The template always displays "Try again!" even though through the Admin I have ensured that some are True and some are False.

Comment: try no sending the manager itself via context, do `example = Example.objects.all()` and in the template, iterate that way `{% for x in example %}`. I am not sure, but try

Answer (score 2):

Your views.py should be like this

```
def home(request):
    example = Example.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'example': example})
```

and html should be

```
{% for x in example %}
{% if x is True %}
    <p>Congratulations!</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Try again!</p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The is a simple way I thought of handling boolean related option field in a form

Model.py:

```
class example(models.Model):
 is_online = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Example.html:

```
<div class="form-row">
 <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
  <label class="sr-only">Class Type</label>
   <select name="types" class="form-control">
    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Type (All)</option>
    <option value="True"
     {% if 'True' == values.types %}
      selected
     {% endif %}
    >Online</option>
    <option value="False"
     {% if 'False' == values.types %}
      selected
     {% endif %}
    >Classroom</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
```

View.py

```
# Types
if 'types' in request.GET:
    types = request.GET['types']
    if types == 'True':
        queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(is_online=True)
    elif types == 'False':
        queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(is_online=False)
```

Comment: <select name="has_washroom" type="number" class="form-control form-select" id="has_washroom">
                                                <option value="0" {% if 'False' == ParkingLot.has_washroom %}selected="true"{% endif %}>No Washroom</option>
                                                <option value="1" {% if 'True' == ParkingLot.has_washroom %}selected="true"{% endif %}>Washroom Available</option>
                                            </select>
Doesnt Work